# Android remove cardview padding

Tags: android-cardview

From everything I have read, I should have cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" in my XML file to prevent padding between each cardview.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/name"
        android:layout_below="@id/name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Yet, on my LG phone running 4.4.2, I am seeing white space i.e. padding between the cards. I deliberately set the background to light green.

Here is the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2il9.png)

Comment: I can't find the link again, but in another StackOverflow question, the suggestion of using:      `cardview:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="0dp"`  works;  I needed both.